# Why is my lenght in Array Mod not matching up with Transform Menu in 3d veiw?

Tags: modifiers

Made array of boards..wanted a Spec length of 24" in Array with a 1/2 gap.
Array did not work(?)

Entered 24" in my Transform Menu but my array length box = 60"

x = 48"
y = 24"
z = 1.6"

Comment: Hello :). This kind of stuff can happen due to non-uniform scale. *(Object > Apply > Scale)*

Comment: Thank You Jachym Michal "WORKED!"

Comment: https://artisticrender.com/how-and-why-do-we-apply-scale-in-blender/